# Plotly Dash callback is being triggered by Output

Tags: plotly-dash

I have a Dash application (written in Python) where some text boxes (html.Div componets) are created and removed based on the values of some radio items.

The target of the application is to send a query to a database when some button is clicked. This is done via a callback that has only one input which is this button (html.Button). The code for the callback looks as follows:

```
@app.callback(
    Output({'type': 'output-textbox', index: ALL}, 'children'),
    Input('submit-button', 'n_clicks'),
)
```

The issue is that this callback is being triggered anytime a component of type 'output-textbox' is created or removed (which happens based on another callback that takes the radio items as input as mentioned earlier). My question is: Is this the normal behavior for Dash? (My understanding is that a callback is triggered only when input is changed). Is there anyway to prevent this callback from being triggered when the Output components change?

The application layout looks as follows (it contains further components, but those are the ones relevant to this question):

```
def serve_layout():
    app_layout = html.Div([
        html.Div(children=[
            html.Div(children=[
                html.Button(id='submit-button', n_clicks=0),
                dcc.Loading(id='responses', children=create_textboxes())
            ]),
            html.Div(children=[
                html.Div(children=[
                    html.Div(children=[
                        dcc.RadioItems(['Yes', 'No'], id='radioitem-1'),
                        dcc.RadioItems(['Yes', 'No'], id='radioitem-2'),
                    ])
                ])
            ])
        ])
    ])
```

The function to create the textboxes looks like follows:

```
def create_texboxes(textbox_1=True, textbox_2=True):
    children= []
    if textbox_1:
        children.append(html.Div(id={'type': 'output-textbox', 'index': 1}))
    if textbox_2:
        children.append(html.Div(id={'type': 'output-textbox', 'index': 2}))
    return children
```

The callback and the function where the textboxes are displayed/ hidden based on the radio items' values are as follows:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('responses', 'children'),
    Input('radioitem-1', 'value'),
    Input('radioitem-2', 'value'),
)

def update_textboxes(textbox_1, textbox_2):
    if textbox_1 == 'Yes':
        display_textbox_1 = True
    else:
        display_textbox_1 = False
    if textbox_2 == 'Yes':
        display_textbox_2 = True
    else:
        display_textbox_2 = False
    return create_texboxes(display_textbox_1, display_textbox_2)
```

Comment: Can you share the (minimum) layout and maybe the code related to the radio items so we have all the necessary info to answer the pb please?

Comment: Note that all of the callbacks in a Dash app are (by default) executed with the initial value of their inputs when the app is first loaded. You can disable this behavior globally by passing `prevent_initial_callbacks=True` to the Dash constructor, or for specific callback(s) by adding `prevent_initial_call=True` to the decorator. @see [When Are Callbacks Executed?](https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks#when-are-callbacks-executed?)

Comment: @thmslmr I have added the layout and the relevant callbacks

Comment: @EricLavault I understand. However the issue here is not limited to the initial loading of the app but every time these components are added or removed. This doesn't happen when other components are added/ removed to the layout though (it happens only with the output textboxes)